# Get a pop up box to show the user details?

Tags: list, jquery, popup

I have a list called Contact, where I have three fields , 
1. Name
2. Mobile
3. Email.

Now I created a Content Editor, Where I will display all the names of the employees. Now how can I create a pop up box (**Like the one we will get from this site**) to show the **Mobile and Email** of the selected users.

Thank you for all the help!!

Comment: Are you using a Content Query Webpart instead of a Content Placeholder?

Comment: @DanielButler I apologize it is Content Editor!!

Comment: How are you retreiving the list items so far, is it by the client side object model?

Comment: Currently I created a gridview to get all the list items and show as a visual webpart.. Now here I am asking I will manually add the Employee name (only 5 members) in a Content Editor and on click of each employee can I show his Other details from the list (such as Mobile and Email) in a dialogue / pop up box ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably should use the [SharePoint Modal Dialog Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058.aspx) to display it.

The easiest way would be:

- Create a view with the fields you would like
- View an contact from the list, right click and select Properties on the page to obtain the URL
- Copy the Content ID and fix the URL relative to your page into the following function
- Modify the page where you are displaying the list of ids with a URL of openContactDialog()

  ```
  function openContactDialog(listItemId) {
      var options = {
          url: "../../Lists/Contacts/DispForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=<INSERT ID FOR VIEW HERE>&IsDlg=1&ID=" + listItemId,
          width: 800,
          height: 600,
          title: "Contact Information",
      };
      SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
  }
  ```

To call the function from the GridView, use the following as an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="javascript:openContactDialog('<%# Eval("Id") %>');"><%# Eval("Name") %></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed info, let me try with this. Since I am a very new programmer everything looking so difficult !!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean popup box = tooltip window? :) There are actually [plenty of jquery tooltip plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/), you can use any of them.

Comment: That was a great link Omlin, However how can I add this  to my Content editor webpart? Its like a dialogue box !!

Comment: You can edit HTML code in Content Editor WebPart. Search for `HTML` button on ribbon.